# Abrir select open value com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia, estou com uma solicitação que não conseguindo achar nada parecido com isso.

Ao clicar no select, ele envia uma requisição para o javascript e preenche os dados, e ao preencher, necessito que esses dados aparecam.

Até preencher, tudo bem, funciona direitinho, mas abrir o select logo em seguida, não está saindo.

Tentei com algo do tipo

```
 //preenche os dados
 $.each(dados, function (i, d) {
     $('<option>').val(d.Id).text(d.Descricao).appendTo(selectbox);
 });

 //abre os dados preenchidos
 selectbox.show().focus().click();
```

Esse código de cima foi o máximo que achei para abrir um select mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente não tem uma solução `javascript` "correta" para fazer isso.

A razão é que não há definição de um evento que forneça isso para o elemento `select` definido no W3.org: [the-select-element.html](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/the-select-element.html)

Nem nada no mozilla.org achamos algo relevante: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Claro que é possível tentar algumas coisas, mas como cada motor dos navegadores pode implementar o funcionamento do `select` de forma diferente, não há garantias que funcione em um outro.

Pensando de forma lógica, você tentou o correto, forçar o focus e ainda o click. Outra opção seria forçar o click através de um evento:

```
var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
document.getElementById("id-do-select").dispatchEvent(event);
```

Mas também não há garantia que funcione, portante a resposta é que não há um método correto/confiável para fazer isso.

Coloquei as duas ideias aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/w0s4xmc0/31798/
e testando com Chrome 68, FF 61, IE 10/Edge e Opera 36, só funcionou no Opera :(

Answer (score 1):

Uma possível solução é abrir o select por meio de alguns truques de `CSS`, como descrito abaixo, porém não consegui fazer que quando abra o `select`, o foco fique no item onde o `selected` se encontra.

Onde tem `$(el).val() != 'teste2'` vai o valor que você quer que já venha preenchido...

```js
function simulateClick() {

        var $target = $("#openSelect");
        var $clone = $target.clone().removeAttr('id');
        $clone.val($target.val()).css({
            overflow: "auto",
            position: 'absolute',
            'z-index': 999,
            left: $target.offset().left,
            top: $target.offset().top + $target.outerHeight(),
            width: $target.outerWidth()
        }).attr('size', $clone.find('option').length > 10 ? 10 : $clone.find('option').length).change(function() {
            $target.val($clone.val());
        }).on('click blur keypress',function(e) {
         if(e.type !== "keypress" || e.which === 13)
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $('body').append($clone);
        $clone.focus();

}

$("option").each(function(key, el){
  if($(el).val() != 'teste2') $(el).removeAttr("selected");
  else $(el).attr("selected", "true");
}, simulateClick() )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="openSelect">
  <option value="teste1">teste1</option>
  <option value="teste2">teste2</option>
  <option value="teste3">teste3</option>
  <option value="teste4">teste4</option>
</select>
```

Referência : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234971/simulate-click-on-select-element-with-jquery